# From where concept of saath janm came?

Tags: rebirth

Which scriptures mention about 7 births. If everyone has 7 births and then gets Moksha, then what is the necessity of believing in God

Comment: Is your main concern is how the concept of 7 births came? OR necessity of believing in God cause both are totally different questions.Also pls. let us know that from where you come to know that after 7 births everyone will get the moksha , to understand your question better.

Comment: https://www.mostinside.com/7-interesting-facts-about-hindu-religions-concept-of-reincarnation/

Comment: i want to.know how the concept of 7 births came. Sorry for the confusion